# Flutter test future throws an error, can't test exception

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to test a function that returns a Future

however when you pass in bad parameters it throws an exception.

I'm trying to write tests for this, however when I run

```
test("When a new practice is created with an empty name, an exception is thrown", () async {
      //arrange
      //act
      //assert
      expect(newUserRepository.saveUser("", "Test"), throwsA(TypeMatcher<Exception>()));
    });
```

I get the following

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'TypeMatcher<Exception>'>
  Actual: <Instance of 'Future<void>'>
   Which: threw ?:<Exception>
```

Any way I can get it to pass this test?

My saveUser function

```
Future<void> saveUser(String username, String practiceName) async {
    if (username == null || username.isEmpty || practiceName == null || practiceName.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception("Unable to save empty username or pracice name");
    }

    var firebaseUser = await userRepository.getFirebaseUser();
    var newUser = DomainUser(userName: username, email: firebaseUser.email);
    await userRepository.saveUser(newUser);

    var newPractice = DomainPractice(users: [newUser.email], practiceName: practiceName);
    await practiceRepository.savePractice(newPractice);
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Can you put the code of newUserRepository.saveUser()

Comment: Updated with the function